# DOM. Как примененить стиль для body в js

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Есть пара стилей в css

```
.normal{
    background: #2e9435;
    transition: background 0.8s ease;
}
.warning{
    background: #c70000;
    transition: background 0.8s ease;
}
```

Есть событие js (в котором я не уверен)

```
function alarm(){
   document.body.style = "warning";}
```

И страница с кнопкой, на которую записано

```
onclick="alarm()"
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: что значит `style = "warning";` ?

Comment: Прочитайте https://yandex.ru/turbo?text=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.internet-technologies.ru%2Farticles%2Fdobavlyaem-i-udalyaem-css-klassy-pri-pomoschi-javascript.html

Comment: вы хотите добавлять класс к body динамически?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Хороший гайд как манипулировать классами DOM](https://html5.by/blog/javascript-classlist-api/)

```js
function alarm() {
  document.body.classList.toggle("warning");
}
```

```css
.normal{
    background: #2e9435;
    transition: background 0.8s ease;
}
.warning{
    background: #c70000;
    transition: background 0.8s ease;
}
```

```html
<body class="normal">
<p>lorem</p>
<input type="button" value="toggle class" onclick="alarm()"/>
</body>
```